# SSAS problem measure gives random sum value each process

Tags: ssis, ssas

I did create a OLAP Cube. Yet the values in measure are completly random each time I process it.
I have a cube that has a dimension with attributes like rowId, TransId, TransValue. The values in attribute are correct but when I added the value as a sum Measure the values are completly random. What could be wrong with it?
The transactions are indeed duplicated if they contain more lines yet the value don't match anything.
It looks like this:

```
rowId TransId TransValue SumTransValue
1     trans1  12345      6234
2     trans2  11111      412
3     trans2  11111      412
4     trans2  11111      412
5     trans3  -55       -894
6     trans3  -55       -894
```

[image]

```
("[Measures].[ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT]";$A$1;"[dim]. 
[MAINACCOUNTVALUE]";"[dim].[MAINACCOUNTVALUE].&[3011000]";"[dim]. 
[JOURNALNUMBER]";"[dim].[JOURNALNUMBER].&[PAF-004642550]";"[dim].[My 
Key]";"[dim].[My Key].&[6402387]";"[dim].[ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT]";" 
[dim].[ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT].&[-1.02E3]&[PAF-004642550]")
```

When I look in excel the calculations looks like this. THe value -1020 is correct but what the hell is this 182703,54? I don't understand it.

Comment: I did not write the MDX, just added the TransValue in measure group as Sum function. It's just a flat table, when execute the query the values are right, and TransValue added to myDimension gives correct value too. Only this SumTransValue that is just a dragged TransValue into measue with Sum gives this random values.

Comment: I would understand it if the values would be duplicated per transaction but they are not and they change every time I process the cube without any changes to the tabel content.